# How to convert a long long in const char* in c++

Tags: c++

I tried to use a function that converts a `long long` to an `const char*` because the function `socket->write` in my code needs a parameter with the datatype `const char *data`. But if I look to my output, `convertedLabel` is nothing and I don't know why. I think I haven't the right converting function.

My code:

```
void ServerNet::sendData(long long label270) {
    std::cout << "First:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << label270 << std::endl;

    //Error is here:
    const char* convertedLabel = reinterpret_cast<char * const>(label270);

    std::cout << "Then:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << convertedLabel << std::endl;
    socket->write(convertedLabel);
}
```

Output:

```
First:
2173457687
Then:
```

Comment: If it looks like "nothing", then it was a pointer to a literal `'\0'` (by chance probably). What did you intend to send on the wire?

Comment: @Coop4Free If you need such a casting it means that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ext3h has a good point. Are you trying to write the `long long` in text format or binary? Is the value `0` just one byte, or `sizeof(long long)` bytes in your protocol? And if the latter, why is that wire protocol so underspecificied? You can't rely on `sizeof(long lon)==sizeof(std::int64_t)`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow or just using a C API.

Comment: That line marked "Error is here" is, indeed, an error. `const char*` and `char * const` are two different types; the result of that `reinterpret_cast` cannot be assigned to `convertedLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void SendData(const char* Data) {
    std::cout << Data << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    long long label270 = 2173457687;
    SendData(std::to_string(label270).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With yours guys tipps I handled the problem. Here's the solution:

```
void ServerNet::sendData(long long label270) {
    std::string convertedLabel = std::to_string(label270);
    const char *test = convertedLabel.c_str();
    socket->write(test);
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: It looks like @akk0rd87 correctly guessed your intentions. You should upvote their answer and consider marking it as accepted.